# windows phone 7 errors

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxpaP.png

> 'InitializeComponent' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/na20Z.png

> 'CountTextBlock' is not a member of 'Tally.Tally.MainPage'.

I have no idea why i am getting these errors. Please check the links for images of the errors. I have converted the code from c# to Vb.net using many converters. All of them gives the same conversion.

Code :-

```
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Input
Imports System.Windows.Navigation
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Controls
Imports Tally.WindowsPhoneApp ' For the Setting class



Namespace Tally
    Partial Public Class MainPage
        Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
        Private count As Integer = 0
        ' Remember what the user typed, for future app activations or launches:
        Private savedCount As New Setting(Of Integer)("SavedCount", 0)

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        ' Handle a tap anywhere on the page (other than the Button)
        Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeftButtonDown(ByVal e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e)
            Me.count += 1
            Me.CountTextBlock.Text = Me.count.ToString("N0")
        End Sub

        ' Handle a tap on the button
        Private Sub ResetButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
            Me.count = 0
            Me.CountTextBlock.Text = Me.count.ToString("N0")
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedFrom(ByVal e As NavigationEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnNavigatedFrom(e)
            ' Persist state when leaving for any reason (Deactivated or Closing):
            Me.savedCount.Value = Me.count
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As NavigationEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)
            ' Restore persisted state:
            Me.count = Me.savedCount.Value
            Me.CountTextBlock.Text = Me.count.ToString("N0")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Settings.vb**

```
Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage
Namespace WindowsPhoneApp
    ' Encapsulates a key/value pair stored in Isolated Storage ApplicationSettings
    Public Class Setting(Of T)
        Private name As String
        'INSTANT VB NOTE: The variable value was renamed since Visual Basic does not allow class members with the same name:
        Private value_Renamed As T
        'INSTANT VB NOTE: The variable defaultValue was renamed since Visual Basic does not allow class members with the same name:
        Private defaultValue_Renamed As T
        Private hasValue As Boolean
        Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal defaultValue As T)
            Me.name = name
            Me.defaultValue_Renamed = defaultValue
        End Sub
        Public Property Value() As T
            Get
                ' Check for the cached value
                If Not Me.hasValue Then
                    ' Try to get the value from Isolated Storage
                    If Not IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(Me.name, Me.value_Renamed) Then
                        ' It hasn’t been set yet
                        Me.value_Renamed = Me.defaultValue_Renamed
                        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings(Me.name) = Me.value_Renamed
                    End If
                    Me.hasValue = True
                End If

                Return Me.value_Renamed
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As T)
                ' Save the value to Isolated Storage
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings(Me.name) = value
                Me.value_Renamed = value
                Me.hasValue = True
            End Set
        End Property
        Public ReadOnly Property DefaultValue() As T
            Get
                Return Me.defaultValue_Renamed
            End Get
        End Property
        ' "Clear" cached value:
        Public Sub ForceRefresh()
            Me.hasValue = False
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating new pages in your project first via the built-in Visual Studio facilities, then copy and paste your translated code on top of the auto-generated code.

I believe the problem is that you're missing the rest of the `.designer.vb` code files that are normally auto-generated when you're creating these pages by hand.

Comment: I created the project using visual studio...then i replaced the code with the converted code...though i don,t see any `.designer.vb` file.

Comment: @SunnyBhattacharjee: It is in the folder with your project.  You won't see it in Visual Studio unless you click the `Show All Files` button in Solution Explorer.  After that, it will show up if you click the `>` button next to your form's `.vb` file.

Comment: @SunnyBhattacharjee: My point is that you probably didn't *replace* the code.  You probably just added it.  You'll have to add the page, and copy/paste the code over it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not donw any VB programming, but I decided to try it, just for the sake of this question. As @Merlyn says, you should be fine if you just use a visual studio template to develop your app. I created mine with the basic Windows phone application project template for VB. The way this works is similar to the way it works in C#. InitializeComponent() is a public method that is defined in the associated .g.vb of your .xaml file(In this case, mainpage.xaml). In order to view what it contains, just *go to definition* on the InitializeComponent call in the mainPage code behind constructor. This is what a basic definition would contain. The code inside this routine knows how to load the controls that you have defined in xaml in to corresponding .NET framework objects.

```
 Public Sub InitializeComponent()
        If _contentLoaded Then
            Return
        End If
        _contentLoaded = true
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Me, New System.Uri("/PhoneApp1;component/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative))
        Me.LayoutRoot = CType(Me.FindName("LayoutRoot"),System.Windows.Controls.Grid)
        Me.TitlePanel = CType(Me.FindName("TitlePanel"),System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel)
        Me.ApplicationTitle = CType(Me.FindName("ApplicationTitle"),System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock)
        Me.PageTitle = CType(Me.FindName("PageTitle"),System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock)
        Me.ContentPanel = CType(Me.FindName("ContentPanel"),System.Windows.Controls.Grid)
    End Sub
```

If you are looking for this file, Its in obj/Data/MainPage.g.i.vb